# Dynamic shortcut link in PWA

Tags: next.js, progressive-web-apps, next-pwa

We can specify the shortcut link in manifest.json file like:

```js
"shortcuts": [

   {

      "name": "Shortcut name to show in the menu",

      "description": "A description of what the shortcut does",

      "url": "Link to shortcut",

      "icons": [

         {

            "src": "/icons/play-later.svg",

            "type": "image/svg+xml",

            "purpose": "any"

         }

      ]

   }

]
```

But how can add the dynamic shortcut in it. Like my web-app is fully dynamic (its like google classroom), and when the user joins the new room I want to create a shortcut link for each room they have joined/created.